# Best JNI Pattern for wrapping C++ Objects?

Tags: java, c++, oop, java-native-interface

I am working on a Java API where many of the Java objects are really wrappers for equivalent C++ objects. The Java objects create the C++ objects and are responsible for freeing them when they are no longer required. I am wondering about the best pattern to use for this, I can see two possible options:

1. Construct the C++ object in the constructor using a static native method call and final variable to hold the native handle.

   ```
   public abstract class NativeBackedObject1 implements java.lang.AutoCloseable {

       protected final long _nativeHandle;
       protected final AtomicBoolean _nativeOwner;

       protected NativeBackedObject1(final long nativeHandle) {
           this._nativeHandle = nativeHandle;
           this._nativeOwner = new AtomicBoolean(true);
       }

       @Override
       public close() {
           if(_nativeOwner.copareAndSet(true, false)) {
               disposeInternal();
           }
       }

       protected abstract void disposeInternal();
   }

   public SomeFoo1 extends NativeBackendObject1 {
       public SomeFoo1() {
           super(newFoo());
       }

       @Override
       protected final void disposeInternal() {
           //TODO: any local object specific cleanup
           disposeInternal(_nativeHandle);
       }

       private native static long newFoo();
       private native disposeInternal(final long nativeHandle);
   }
   ```
2. Construct the C++ object in the constructor using an instance native method call and a non-final variable to hold the native handle.

   ```
   public abstract class NativeBackedObject2 implements java.lang.AutoCloseable {
       protected long _nativeHandle;
       protected boolean _nativeOwner;

       protected NativeBackedObject2() {
           this._nativeHandle = 0;
           this._nativeOwner = true;
       }

       @Override
       public void close() {
           synchronized(this) {
               if(_nativeOwner && _nativeHandle != 0) {
                   disposeInternal();
                   _nativeHandle = 0;
                   _nativeOwner = false;
               }
           }
       }

       protected abstract void disposeInternal();
   }

   public SomeFoo2 extends NativeBackendObject2 {
       public SomeFoo2() {
           super();
           _nativeHandle = newFoo();
       }

       @Override
       protected final void disposeInternal() {
           //TODO: any local object specific cleanup
           disposeInternal(_nativeHandle);
       }

       private native long newFoo();
       private native disposeInternal(final long nativeHandle);
   }
   ```

At the moment I am thinking that (1) is the better approach, because:

- a. It means that I can set `_nativeHandle` to be immutable (`final`). So I don't need to worry about concurrent access to it or unexpected changes (the code is actually more complex that these simplistic examples).
- b. Due to the constructor, I have formalised in the design, that any sub-class of `NativeBackedObject` is the owner of its respective native object (represented by `_nativeHandle`), as it cannot be constructed without it.

Are there any advantages of approach (2) over (1), or any problems with approach (1)?

I could also see an alternative pattern to approach (1), let's call it approach (3):

```
public abstract class NativeBackedObject3 implements java.lang.AutoCloseable {
    protected final long _nativeHandle;
    protected final AtomicBoolean _nativeOwner;

    protected NativeBackedObject3() {
        this._nativeHandle = newInternal();
        this._nativeOwner = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    }

    @Override
    public close() {
        if(_nativeOwner.copareAndSet(true, false)) {
            disposeInternal();
        }
    }

    protected abstract long newInternal();
    protected abstract void disposeInternal();
}

public SomeFoo3 extends NativeBackendObject3 {
    public SomeFoo3() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected final void disposeInternal() {
        //TODO: any local object specific cleanup
        disposeInternal(_nativeHandle);
    }

    @Override
    protected long newInternal() {
        return newFoo();
    };

    private native long newFoo();
    private native disposeInternal(final long nativeHandle);
}
```

The advantage of (3) over (1), is that I can move back to a default constructor, which could help with creating mocks for testing etc. The major disadvantage though, is that I can no longer pass additional params to `newFoo()`.

Perhaps there are other approaches that I have missed? Suggestions welcome...

Comment: What kind of life cycle will your NativeBackedObjects have?

Comment: The lifecycle will be manually managed by the API consumer, I implemented AutoCloseable so they have the option of using try-with-resources to manage the cleanup.

Comment: Are you going to be doing any multithreading?  I'm also trying to figure out your `_nativeOwner` AtomicBoolean.  Given that is a `final` instance variable of the `NativeBackedObject` created by that object's constructor, unless you have additional code that's not shown that changes what you define as ownership, I don't see any need for that Boolean.  The current `NativeBackedObject` has **the** reference to your native object, obtained by I assume via `new` in your native code.  You'd have to pass the ownership around, and I'd avoid that if at all possible.  It'd be an O&M nightmare.

Comment: Regarding options 1 and 3, is it possible to provide multiple constructors for both the Java and native objects?  A bare default constructor along with whatever other constructors you might need?  You'd have to implement multiple `private native long newFoo(...)` calls with differing arguments, but most of those would just be simply passed through to the native `new Foo(...)` constructor.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am not sure what "O&M" stands for. Sometimes the memory management of the underlying C++ object, is disowned by the Java object, as the object later becomes the responsibility of another object the C++ API, hence needing the `_nativeOwner flag`. There is some multithreading, which is why I need safe access to _nativeOwner and _nativeHandle.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I could possibly have multiple constructors but I would rather avoid this, as multiple constructors in the super-class means that every sub-class gains complexity as well. My question is really about construction of the object rather than destruction, i.e. is it better to encode the `_nativeHandle` as `final` and require it at construction via a static JNI method call, or alternatively to have it as, non-final and not required in the constructor and to use a non-static JNI method call.

Comment: Would be curious to know if you saw anything wrong with the way I've done it with JavaCPP: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp

Comment: Hey @samuel-audet, that is very cool! Something that I wasn't aware of. I would have to dig in pretty deep into your framework to find out how you manage the lifecycle of objects though. Perhaps you could comment about which pattern you follow in your code generation - 'By Call', 'By Call, Static', 'ByCall, Invoke' from here - https://github.com/adamretter/jni-construction-benchmark or perhaps a different pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried SWIG (http://www.swig.org) which can generate Java wrappers of c++ objects?

```
%typemap(javabody) SWIGTYPE %{
    private long swigCPtr;
    protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

    public $javaclassname(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
        swigCPtr = cPtr;
    }

    public static long getCPtr($javaclassname obj) {
       return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
    }
 %}
```

As documentation for SWIG says, consider simple test class:

```
class Test {
   string str;
public:
  Test() : str("initial") {}
};
```

the output for it is:

```
public class Test {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  protected Test(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(Test obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  // Call C++ destructor
  public synchronized void delete() {
    if(swigCPtr != 0 && swigCMemOwn) {
      swigCMemOwn = false;
          exampleJNI.delete_Test(swigCPtr);
        }
        swigCPtr = 0;
      }

  // Call C++ constructor
  public Test() {
    this(exampleJNI.new_Test(), true);
  }

}
```

Comment: Nope. Do you know what sort of pattern it follows?

Comment: Thanks @tomasz-jarosik  that is very interesting. So it looks like SWIG is doing "By Call" from the patterns I documented here - https://github.com/adamretter/jni-construction-benchmark

Comment: Cool comparison! I think that SWIG uses "By Call, static" as they have static everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The approach "By Call, Static" is indeed most efficient as per the benchmark at
https://github.com/adamretter/jni-construction-benchmark
but [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) basically uses "By Call, Invoke" (which BTW can be made a bit more efficient by caching the `jfieldID`).

The reason why I chose to do it that way is to produce a cleaner Java interface file. The user can decide to either write it manually or let the tool generate it from header files. Either way, it ends up reading like a Java translation of some header files. However, the more cruft we add to that interface, the less it looks like C++, and the harder it becomes to write or read it. (That's one of the many things I don't like about SWIG.)

BTW, it's not forbidden to modify `final` variables from JNI, so that could be another reason why one might want to do it that way.

Of course, it's still possible to modify JavaCPP and support the more computationally efficient way of doing things, but we barely save any time at all that it hasn't proven to be an issue, yet.